# NodeJS Python child process stops writing after one time

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

My Node.js parent program spawns a python child process and will send it text data. This occurs just fine for one time, after this the Node.js process no longer sends the text data. Implementation show below:

The process is pawned as:

`python = spawn('python3', ['-u', 'main.py'], { stdio: ['pipe'] });`

and it gets back the data to the parent:

```
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    dataToSend = data.toString();
    console.log("DATA TO SEND ", dataToSend)
});
```

I continuously recieive data from a socket connection and need to send that data to the python script. Which is done so by:

```
python.stdin.write(received.toString()+ "\n")
python.stdin.end()
```

This process works fine for one time, on the next time around the above code does not work.

The python script receives data by:

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Comment: this lacks a bit of information but it looks like your python script terminates no ? maybe realines only reads the information availible at your call, then returns, in which case you should loop around it ?

Comment: @laenNoCode This is mot the case, there is already a while loop around readlines().